# How do C functions like fscanf() and fgets() remember where in the file to start reading from?

Tags: c

How do C functions like `fscanf()` and `fgets()` remember where in the file to start reading from? For instance, when reading a file using `fscanf()`, it seems to remember where it last left terminated, rather than starting from the beginning of the file again. How exactly does this work?

Comment: That's what the `FILE *` parameter is for.

Comment: @kaylum can you please elaborate? I'd like to get a good conceptual understanding of this. I should mention that I am well aware of using FILE * but I was not aware that it undertook this function. Please elaborate.

Comment: They store the position that was last read. This is the same thing you are adjusting with `fseek`.

Comment: @M.M I thought FILE * only stored the file location in directories? So it also stores exactly where INSIDE the file functions like fscanf() and fgets() have read/written up to?

Comment: That parameter stores internal state, including the `fd` (file descriptor). The `fd` is managed by the kernel and the kernel keeps track of the position in the file (and other things) for each fd.

Comment: It stores whatever is necessary to make those functions work as specified, this may vary between implementations

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/FILE/

Comment: @azavalla That doesn't explain how it remembers where in the file it was last terminated.

Comment: @kaylum so the FILE * object stores the file descriptor. The fd stores information about the file location, including the location in the file that was read up to? And this fd is managed by the kernel.   Is this all correct?

Comment: **Just look at your user name.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `FILE *` parameter points to a buffer and a file handle (see the `fileno()` function).

The actual where is remembered in the kernel in the file structure.

There is a legend that the `FILE *` pointer points into the file. This is not literally true, but it might as well be true for the interpretation of the beginning programmer.

In fact what happens is as follows: Every process has an array in kernel of type `struct file` (this type is not defined in userspace so don't go looking for it) that contains all of its open files. A handle is returned by the `open()` syscall that is merely an index into the array. The function `fileno()` retrieves the handle from the FILE * pointer returned by `fopen()` and can be manipulated directly. This is usually a bad idea except for accessing `ioctl()` or `fctl()` as you will end up fighting with the internal buffer in the `FILE` object.

One of the members of `struct file` is `loff_t f_pos` which is the exact location in bytes the kernel `read()` or `write()` stopped at. This is buffered in `FILE` which knows how many bytes it read ahead or pended for a later write for you.